# How can translate umlauts with jquery.i18n-properties?

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-plugins, internationalization

I'm working on a jquery mobile application and trying to translate it with i18n-properties plugin. Unfortunaley the encoding is wrong, because in the browser I get  "f�r" instead of "für". What can I do?

thank you flo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, problem fixed. I just translated my bundle to UTF-8.